# Can mod_fcgid maintain a hard-minimum number of available appserver processes?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, cisco-catalyst

...and if so, how?

I'm using Apache2 + mod_fcgid to serve a perl Catalyst application, on a box that I own, and I'd like for mod_fcgid to maintain a minimum number of spun-up processes ready to go.  The docs say that  [FcgidMinProcessesPerClass](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidminprocessesperclass) only enforces a

> minimum number of processes that will be retained in a process class after finishing requests

How do I get apache to start up with a certain number of appserver subprocesses on an idle server without using artificial load to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Jeff Trawick, the answer is no.

Here's a feature request to address it:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52174